# How to keep company field optional in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, form-validation

I want to override Shipping address field
At present, the shipping address, **Company Name** is a required field

https://www.screencast.com/t/8PgjgHxoM

Occurs in the `checkout` page.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456794/magento-make-the-field-company-required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is still not working and you are using magento 2 enterprise , then you can also try following way as well :

Create file : app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>     
        <section id="customer" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="company_config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Show Company Configuration</label>       
                <field id="company" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Show Company</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Nooptreq</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Backend\Show\Customer</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

But I would recommend first debug your code customization , this procedure generally used for customer EAV attribute for address options .

Comment: I Used SQL UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '0' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 27;  to get the solution

Comment: I think this code will do the same that's why suggested but it is not recommended to do any change on EAV tables directly from DB

Answer (score 2):

You can try following:

> Admin Login ->Store->configuration-> Customers->Customer Configuration -> Expand Name and Address  option section -> Show Company (Optional).

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/udgF75EDlCq
Expanded Name &  Adress option not showing up option @shashank

Comment: You are using community or enterprise ?

Comment: Enterprise Edition

Comment: I think there is some break in the code because this option is available in following location by default without any customization. try to disable custom modules and check first.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me time.